# how to sort in ascending order multiple decimal numbers in list using c#.net

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

How to sort list in ascending order multiple decimal numbers  in c#.net

given this list for Example:

> 0 1
>
> 1.2
>
> 1.0.2
>
> 1.0.0.3
>
> 1.0.3.0.1
>
> 2.2.9
>
> 0.0.0.1

Comment: Those aren't decimal numbers. How do you set those into your list in your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort List of Strings By Version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792182/sort-list-of-strings-by-version)

Answer (score 1):

```
var doubleList = new List<double>{
    0,1,1.2,1.0
    // etc...
};
```

Using linq you could:

```
var ascSortedList = doubleList.OrderBy(d => d);
```

Or without linq:

```
doubleList.Sort();
foreach (string value in doubleList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```